# Javascript: Populating a html drop-down list based on onchange data from another dropdown using

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Ok. I have scoured for hours. I can't seem to find the answer to this. I have tried several different ways of typing the code, but I can't seem to get it going. so, here goes.

I have figured out that the first box, pcclan, is registering the onchange. however, it doesn't seem to be registering the selectedIndex, value, or text in the dropdown. I will state that the first dropdown clan is rendered by way of php. however, i have attempted it by rendering it with javascript as well. No matter what I do, I can't get this. Anyway, on with the show.

based on pcclan, which is a dropdown of 12 or 13 options, it is supposed to go through an if else if argument, find the proper clan, and populate a second dropdown, named famnames, based on the clan chosen.

I have tried everything that i know of, to get this done, and it's just not working. so, i have finally come to you all. I feel it is something simple that i am missing. I also feel it is in the if else if. i have tried every way i can think of and could find to target the first dropdown, pcclan. also, as it stands, the famnames drop down populates with only the crabclan array. here is the code as it stands.

```
var pcclan = new Array("Crab","Crane","Dragon","Lion","Phoenix","Mantis","Scorpion","Unicorn","Imperial","Badger","Dragonfly","Hare","Monkey","Oriole","Ox","Sparrow","Tortoise","Monk", "Ronin","Merchant");
var crabfams = new Array("Hida","Hiruma","Kaiu","Kuni","Toritaka","Yasuki");
var cranefams = new Array("Asahina","Daidoji","Doji","Kakita");
var dragonfams = new Array("Kitsuki","Mirumoto","Tamori","Togashi");
var lionfams = new Array("Ikoma","Akodo","Kitsu","Matsu");
var mantisfams = new Array("Kitsune","Moshi","Tsuruchi","Yoritomo");
var phoenixfams = new Array("Agasha","Asako","Isawa","Shiba");
var scorpionfams = new Array("Bayushi","Shosuro","Soshi","Yogo");
var unicornfams = new Array("Horiuchi","Ide","Iuchi","Moto","Shinjo","Utaku");
var imperialfams = new Array("Miya","Otomo","Seppun","Toturi");
var badgerfams = new Array("Ichiro");
var dragonflyfams = new Array("Tonbo");
var harefams = new Array("Usagi","Ujina");
var monkeyfams = new Array("Toku","Fuzaki");
var oriolefams = new Array("Tsi");
var oxfams = new Array("Morito");
var sparrowfams = new Array("Suzume");
var tortoisefams = new Array("Kasuga");
var monkfams = new Array("Monk");
var roninfams = new Array("Ronin");
var merchantfams = new Array("Fuuki","Kaeru","Ryousie");
var nothin = new Array("Please Choose a Family","---");

function remfams()
{
var e = document.getElementById("famnames");
if (e.options.length > 0)
{
    var count=0;
    for ( ; count < e.options.length ;)
    {
        e.remove(count);count = 0;
    }
}
}

function popclans()
{
var clansdd = document.getElementById("pcclan");
for (var i=0; i < pcclan.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(clansdd, pcclan[i], pcclan[i]);
    }
}

function addfams(selectbox,text,value )
{
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = text;
optn.value = value;
selectbox.options.add(optn);
}

function getfams()
{
var clansdd = document.getElementById("pcclan");
var index = clansdd.selectedIndex;
var clansddvalue = clansdd.text;
var famnames = document.getElementById("famnames");
if (clansddvalue = "Crab")
{
for (var i=0; i < crabfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, crabfams[i], crabfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Crane"){
for (var i=0; i < cranefams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, cranefams[i], cranefams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Dragon") {
for (var i=0; i < dragonfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, dragonfams[i], dragonfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Lion") {
for (var i=0; i < lionfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, lionfams[i], lionfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Mantis") {
for (var i=0; i < mantisfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, mantisfams[i], mantisfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Phoenix") {
for (var i=0; i < phoenixfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, phoenixfams[i], phoenixfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Scorpion") {
for (var i=0; i < scorpionfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, scorpionfams[i], scorpionfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Unicorn") {
for (var i=0; i < unicornfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, unicornfams[i], unicornfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Imperial") {
for (var i=0; i < imperialfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, imperialfams[i], imperialfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Badger") {
for (var i=0; i < badgerfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, badgerfams[i], badgerfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Dragonfly") {
for (var i=0; i < dragonflyfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, dragonflyfams[i], dragonflyfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Hare") {
for (var i=0; i < harefams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, harefams[i], harefams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Monkey") {
for (var i=0; i < monkeyfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, monkeyfams[i], monkeyfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Oriole") {
for (var i=0; i < oriolefams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, oriolefams[i], oriolefams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Ox") {
for (var i=0; i < oxfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, oxfams[i], oxfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Sparrow") {
for (var i=0; i < sparrowfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, sparrowfams[i], sparrowfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Tortoise") {
for (var i=0; i < tortoisefams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, tortoisefams[i], tortoisefams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Monk") {
for (var i=0; i < monkfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, monkfams[i], monkfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Ronin") {
for (var i=0; i < roninfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, roninfams[i], roninfams[i]);
    }
} else if (clansddvalue = "Merchant") {
for (var i=0; i < merchantfams.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, merchantfams[i], merchantfams[i]);
    }
} else {
    for (var i=0; i < nothin.length;++i)
    {
        addfams(famnames, nothin[i], nothin[i]);
    }
}
}
```

I will also fully admit that i code to the point that a new person could dissect it, and it isn't the most efficient. Thank you for any help you can give in advance.

For the frontside of this, the link is http://www.fiveringsonline.net/charsheet.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this <strike>`var clansddvalue = clansdd.text;`</strike> to `var clansddvalue = clansdd.value;`. There is no property called `.text` for select. And more importantly compare values with `==` or `===`. Do not use `=` in if statement. Its the assignment operator.

Comment: tried that before, and retried it, and it didn't work. still only populating the first if statement. thanks for the prompt reply. also tried options[index].value targeting as well.

Comment: i found the problem. it was not only that, but it was also a misnamed variable for the Crab if statement. TY! I would have never caught it if your suggestion hadn't made me change the var name!